# memory error of multi column calculation in large data

Tags: python, pandas, memory, apply, large-data

I want to calculate the existing column and make a new column.

```
df = dd.from_pandas(ddf, npartitions=100)

df['new_column'] = df[['column']].apply(lambda dpan_india_df: dpan_india_df['column']*8000, axis = 1, meta=('object'))
```

How can I use memory efficiently?
For your information, this file is 800M file.

```
  File "Sectorize3.py", line 55, in <lambda>
    df['new_column'] = df[['column']].apply(lambda ddf: ddf['column']*8000, axis = 1, meta=('object'))
MemoryError: occurred at index 1512070
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
df['new_column']=df['column']*8000
```

Comment: I got MemoryError

    lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
MemoryError

Comment: why do you need to use apply if you can do it without it? Or maybe i am missing something, could elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I first did it the way your, but I got a memory error and wrote the apply. But I solved it now. The type of 'column' was not a float. So I changed the type to numeric and succeeded.

Comment: I am stuck with the same error! Can you please elaborate more or share the code after the fix? Thanks!